# Django cripsy form with a custom template for button

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

**Edit**: Not a duplicate, but an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942188/4008056) fixed my issue.

I was able to add `self.helper.form_tag = False` to the helper, which allows me to add my own form tags and button.

I have a need for a `<button>` element for my form submit instead of the layout helper `Submit()` input with Django and django-crispy-form. If I use `{{ my_form|crispy }}` I'm able to do this.

However, with this method all of the other layout elements in the form are ignored. If I switch back to `{% crispy my_form %}` I get the layout back, but then my custom HTML button is ignored.

Is there any way to have a custom HTML submit button while using the Layout helper?

**Note:** If I add the HTML button below the crispy tag the button renders outside of the form, and I cannot iterate through the form fields in the template because my Layout in the Django form is very complex.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
from crispy_forms import layout, helper

class FormName(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = helper.FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(
             layout.layout.HTML("""<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">""",css_class="")
        )
```

**in HTML**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form action="..." method="post" >
   {% comment %} No need to define 'csrf_token' {% endcomment %}
   {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

Comment: I need an actual button, because I need to nest some HTML. I did mention that in my post.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**